# Partition groups are not getting established

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to establish partition groups in Hazelcast 3.8.8. My main goal is to group 4 cluster member that resides in 2 physical machines into 2 partition group. When I enabled the partition groups it seems didn't worked and groups didn't establish. Can you tell me what's I am missing to enable partition groups?

I have tried to enable partition grouping via hazelcast.xml. Tested with **group-type="CUSTOM"** and separated members that reside in my local and our server into two different **member-group**. Members formed a cluster but it seems that partition groups not established. I couldn't see any error message about this but neither there is no confirmation message in logs. Finally, I have enabled **"HOST_AWARE"** and started 2 members in my local with the same network interface and inspected the management center. What I have seen is members behaved like **"PER_MEMBER"** as it is in the default configuration and continued to migrate their backups to each other. I was expecting to see no backup in this case since both would form the partition group.

```
<hazelcast xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
                            http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.6.xsd"
       xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config">
<management-center enabled="true">
    http://217.78.109.101:8080/mancenter
</management-center>
<map name="default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
</map>
<network>
    <port auto-increment="true">5701</port>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false">
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member>217.78.109.101</member>
        </tcp-ip>
    </join>
</network>
<partition-group enabled="true" group-type="HOST_AWARE"/>
```

```
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:35 PM com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator
INFO: Loading 'hazelcast.xml' from classpath.
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:35 PM com.hazelcast.config.AbstractXmlConfigHelper
WARNING: Name of the hazelcast schema location incorrect using default
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:36 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8.8] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [217.78.109.101]
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:36 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8.8] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:36 PM com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8.8] Picked [217.78.109.101]:5702, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5702], bind any local is true
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:36 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Hazelcast 3.8.8 (20171204 - 8e24c57) starting at [217.78.109.101]:5702
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:36 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:36 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:36 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Backpressure is disabled
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Creating TcpIpJoiner
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Starting 8 partition threads
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Starting 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Diagnostics started
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.BuildInfoPlugin
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Plugin:active
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.SystemPropertiesPlugin
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Plugin:active
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.ConfigPropertiesPlugin
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Plugin:active
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.PendingInvocationsPlugin
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Plugin:active: period-millis:30000 threshold:1
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.MetricsPlugin
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.SlowOperationPlugin
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Plugin:active, period-millis:30000
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.PendingInvocationsPlugin
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Plugin:active: period-millis:30000 threshold-millis:5000
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.MemberHazelcastInstanceInfoPlugin
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Plugin:active, period-millis:60000
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.SystemLogPlugin
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Plugin:active: logPartitions:false
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.StoreLatencyPlugin
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Plugin:active: period-millis:60000 resetPeriod-millis:0
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] [217.78.109.101]:5702 is STARTING
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Connecting to /217.78.109.101:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Connecting to /217.78.109.101:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:37 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Established socket connection between /217.78.109.101:62511 and /217.78.109.101:5701
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:38 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.InitConnectionTask
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Could not connect to: /217.78.109.101:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused: connect to address /217.78.109.101:5703]
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:38 PM com.hazelcast.cluster.impl.TcpIpJoiner
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] [217.78.109.101]:5703 is added to the blacklist.
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:43 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Cluster version set to 3.8
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:43 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] 

Members [2] {
    Member [217.78.109.101]:5701 - 4d2cf34a-d64c-4184-98f3-c0d6dc6a6a27
    Member [217.78.109.101]:5702 - 6e23bacc-b0ad-4002-9325-3dffe90417d0 this
}

Kas 08, 2019 2:03:45 PM com.hazelcast.internal.management.ManagementCenterService
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Hazelcast will connect to Hazelcast Management Center on address: 
http://217.78.109.101:8080/mancenter
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:46 PM com.hazelcast.internal.jmx.ManagementService
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] Hazelcast JMX agent enabled.
Kas 08, 2019 2:03:46 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [217.78.109.101]:5702 [dev] [3.8.8] [217.78.109.101]:5702 is STARTED

Process Started.
Random int: 553
sequential.Customer with key 1: Hazel1
Map Size:553
Process Completed. Elapsed Time: 1195 ms
```

Comment: What was the issue when you configured `group-type="CUSTOM"`? How did you conclude this _"When I enabled the partition groups it seems didn't worked and groups didn't establish."_?

Comment: Actually, I didn't exactly conclude that partition groups didn't establish. After 2 cluster members, the management center needs the license to show members so I couldn't check if it is working. Besides as I stated I couldn't see any information about if partition groups established or not in logs so it seemed to me maybe I couldn't enable the partition groups. Actually I was hoping to see if there would be someone to tell me how to check if it partition groups enabled without the management center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there's only single *partition-group*, partitioning mechanism fallbacks to a special *partition-group* type and divides existing members into two partition groups. This is to ensure at least one backup of each partition. Otherwise there won't be any backups and loss of a member will lead to immediate data loss. See in the codebase: [BackupSafeMemberGroupFactory](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/partition/membergroup/BackupSafeMemberGroupFactory.java)

> Update: Regarding whether partition groups are enabled or not...

Unfortunately there's no log or public API to show whether partition groups are in use, apart from management center. But you're right to expect that this information is to be printed in the log. You can file issue at Hazelcast Github repo.

Comment: Please see my comment about your question above.

Comment: Sorry for late comment. 

Since you said there is no way to see the partition group information, I have debugged the BackupSafeMemberGroupFactory in codebase as you stated in your reply and been able to see partition groups are really established. So I have tested my cases in this way. Thank you very much for your solution.  

By the way, as I later find out, I think one way to see if a member is in partition group is to enable diagnostics and examine the **partitions.memberGroupsSize** attribute in the resulted log.